# C# - unable to return List

Tags: c#, class, list, public

i'm trying to return list of objects from a class and get the following error:

`Error  1   Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<EventXmlExtract.Attribute>' is less accessible than property 'EventXmlExtract.EventExtract.AttributeList'    C:\Documents and Settings\eyalk\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Blobs\EventExtractDll\EventExtract.cs  14  32  EventExtractDll`

my code tries return _attributeList:

```
public class EventExtract
{
    private string _type;
    private int _type_id;
    private List<Attribute> _attributeList = new List<Attribute>();

    internal List<Attribute> AttributeList
    {
        get { return _attributeList; }
        set { _attributeList = value; }
    }
}
```

what is the problem ? and how can i retrieve the list ?

Comment: What is the class `Attribute`? I stronly suspect that it's not the System.Attribute class

Comment: then there's the problem. make that Attribute class at least 'internal' and the code will compile just fine

Comment: Could you please show it's definition, as that is the root cause of the problem.

Comment: I've just updated my answer below. Try it out and report back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the class `Attribute` public or internal.

You can't return a list of objects where the class is private, because then the calling code can't access the objects.

Alternatively make the `AttributeList` as restricted as the `Attribute` class, if that is how you want it.

Comment: Unless nested, classes can only be public or internal.

Answer (score 2):

Your *Attribute* class lacks the required visibility.

change the class definition to either

```
public class Attribute
{
```

or

```
internal class Attribute 
{
```

Comment: Unless nested, those two are the only allowed access modifiers on a class element, anyway...

Comment: Makes you wonder how he ended up in that spot in the first place. For the default modifier is _internal_

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you have declared the property as `private`. Try making it as `protected` or `public`.

Comment: The property is not declared as `private`, it's `internal`. The problem is not that the property is too restricted, it's that the type that it returns is too restricted.

Answer (score -1):

Did you include the following?

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

The class compiles fine on my box... :)